# Routes defined in Angular 8 sub-module not evaluated during app startup

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

Since upgrading to Angular 8, my SPA is behaving a bit differently when loading the whole app with a given hash. When loading `#/public/signup`, the app will redirect to `#/trips/home`.

My app is modularized, and app.route.ts only defines:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'trips/home' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'trips/home' },
];

export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot( routes, {
    useHash: true
} );
```

public/public.route.ts then defines

```
const publicRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'public',
        children: [
            { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: 'privacy', component: PrivacyComponent },
            { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'reset/:token', component: ResetComponent },
            { path: 'verify/:token', component: VerifyComponent },
            { path: 'forgotpassword', component: ForgotpasswordComponent },
            { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
        ]
    }
];

export const PublicRoutes = RouterModule.forChild( publicRoutes );
```

It seems there's some lazy loading going on, so at the time of evaluating the hash, the /public paths are not yet known, and I get the catch-all redirect to 'trips/home'. Once the app has loaded, all paths work perfectly.

The PublicModule is defined in app.module.ts (eager loading) as

```
@NgModule( {
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,

        StateModule,
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
        PublicModule,
        StaticDataModule,
        ReportingModule,
        TripsModule,
        // register *after* feature modules and their routes!
        AppRouting,
        // required, even if the array is empty (see sub-modules for registered features)
        EffectsModule.forRoot( [] )
    ],
    exports: [ ],
    providers: [
        Title,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
} )
export class AppModule { }
```

Can someone point me towards the change since Angular 7 on how module-routes are handled?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely surprisingly, the cause wasn't Angular at all. For someone encountering a similar issue:

- Debugging routing during app startup doesn't work, as **Chrome debugger is too slow picking up breakpoints while loading the app**. So the fact you're not hitting a breakpoint doesn't mean the code is not executed.
- Thus: use good old **console.log** statements to track what's happening
- In my case, I only had the effect when compiling with `aot=true`, so I set up a corresponding configuration in angular.json and ran `ng serve --configuration=aot`

This eventually found a conditional check which was buggy. The code was receiving a ngrx store subscription event, I'm guessing there was some change in ngrx 7 to 8.6 which caused my `if` statement to go wrong.

Hopefully the debugging tips above will help.